# Stuck in trying to convert a function from Postgres to Google Big Query

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have the following code in SQLPad using Postgre, and I need to perform the same function in Google BigQuery.

Notes:

- The value of the 'tires' key is a number
- The JSON that I want in is inside brackets.
- The 'cars' column was in JSONB format in SQLPad, but in BigQuery it is in string format.

```
select (jsonb_array_elements(cars)) -> 'tires' as number_of_wheels
from my_table`
```

Comment: Please paste the content of the cars column in string and the expected output.

Comment: @DanielAranda check is this is what you've asked for:

Input:
 [{"id": 123456, "uuid": "2516_uhudfhs_98554", "state": "late", "value": 18989.06, "number": 5, "paid_at": null, "due_date": "2023-01-15", "present_value": 9999.11, "payment_method": null}]


Expected output:
5

Answer (score 0):

I think below will return same result as in PostgreSQL.

```sql
WITH my_table AS (
  SELECT '''[
    {"model":"hyundai", "tires":4, "type":"SUV"},
    {"model":"honda", "tires":4, "type":"Sedan"}
  ]''' cars
)
SELECT JSON_VALUE(car, '$.tires') AS number_of_wheels
  FROM my_table, UNNEST(JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(cars)) car;

-- Query results
+------------------+
| number_of_wheels |
+------------------+
|                4 |
|                4 |
+------------------+
```